# Eloquent model event are saved and created both called when create is used?

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent

In regards to using Eloquent model events, I was wondering how the model events respond to the method calls, if there's any overlap with particular events (*common* events) and if there are, how to approach writing code for such events?

For example, if I have a model for which I call `create()` on, i.e. `Model::create($array)` as I understand, behind the scenes, when I call `create()` the `save()` method is called [as shown in the docs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L567):

```
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return static
 */
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);
    $model->save();
    return $model;
}
```

So keeping this in mind, if I wanted **the same behaviour** for the [`saved()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1178) and [`created()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1226) event, would I simply created an event for the `saved()` event and not need to worry about the `created()` event as the `create()` method is a kind of a wrapper for the `save()` method (as shown above). So I could do this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // covers created and saved events, as create() method triggers save()
    static::saved(function($model) {
        // do xyz
    });
}
```

Or would I need to create two separate methods to listen for both events? Like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($model) {
        // do xyz
    });

    static::saved(function($model) {
        // do xyz
    });
}
```

So just to repeat the questions I stated at the beginning:

- How do model events respond to the method calls
- Is there any overlap with particular events (*common* events, as described above)
- If there are, how to practically approach writing code for such events

Any guidance on understanding this process would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 events around a Model being saved in the database. These are `created`, `updated`, and `saved`.

`created` is called when the model is saved for the first time.

`updated` is called when the model is saved any subsequent time.

`saved` is called any time the model is saved (including when it's first created).

So `saved` is a catch-all.

Additionally, when a model has just been created it has the `wasRecentlyCreated` property set to true.

So if you have just a `saved` event, you can still handle the difference between a create and an update by checking that property.

As for how you go about handling the code, that's down to you.

Personally, if I had some code that was only needed when the model was created I'd use that method. Similarly for updated.

But if I had some shared code that needed to occur every time the model was saved, but additionally needed something special when it was created, I wouldn't create a separate `created` event, I'd just use `saved` and check for `wasRecentlyCreated`.

Comment: How on earth am I supposed to check for $this->wasRecentlyCreated on static ::saved ? Why cant they have a created / saved events like normal people would?

Comment: @alextoader The `saved` method passes you the model that's been saved as its first argument, so just check `wasRecentlyCreated` on that.